# Change icon in Navigation Drawer on the fly

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, drawer

I'm currently trying to change the icon in Navigation Drawer when some event occurs. Is it possible?? I mean that I change the icon - it's no problem:

```
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  
            mDrawerLayout,         
            R.drawable.actionbar_settings,  /* my icon - all Ok! */
            R.string.text1,  
            R.string.text2  
    ) {};
```

I mean what to do if some event fires and I want to change this icon on another? If I repeat the code but with another icon - no success.

```
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  
            mDrawerLayout,         
            R.drawable.new_icon_image,  /* bad news - nothing changes */
            R.string.text1,  
            R.string.text2  
    ) {};
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible?

Yes, but you'll need to call `DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener` and `ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState` to update the indicator and make sure it's synced.

Here's an example:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.new_icon_image, R.string.text1, R.string.text2);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Comment: @user3534709 If you're satisfied with the answer, [will you mark it as accepted, please?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation :(